# Implications of changing wordpress.com associated with Jetpack

Tags: wordpress.com-hosting, plugin-jetpack

Our corporate blog has the Jetpack plugin and it is associated with my personal wordpress.com account. I'd like to change it to our corporate wordpress.com account. If I do that then will I lose the site statistics from before the switch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your stats and subscribers are stored on WordPress.com, and associated to your site URL. The WordPress.com account used to connect Jetpack to WordPress.com doesn't matter.

If you disconnect Jetpack from WordPress.com and then reconnect with another WordPress.com account, all the data associated to that site URL will be back in your dashboard. You won't lose any data.

Comment: When I contacted them they gave me detailed instructions and said, as you say, "Please note that changing the WordPress.com account that is connected to your Jetpack-powered site will not affect your site stats or followers."

Answer (score 2):

You won't lose them, but they won't exist in one place. Old stats will be in your account, and new stats will be in the corporate one.

The Jetpack team is quite responsive, if you ask them to change the account owner of the blog_id, there's a chance they'd be able to do that for you.

Comment: They are quite responsive. When I contacted them what they told me was what the other answer says. Thanks though.

Comment: That's odd, I've switched Jetpack accounts in the past and the stats didn't carry. That must be a new (and highly welcome) feature!

Comment: @MatthewBoynes If you've had issues with Stats in the past, do not hesitate to send us a new email. I'd be happy to have a look!
http://jetpack.me/contact-support/

Comment: @jeherve, that's in the past at this point and not worth the effort, but thank you!